# The set of all rational points in the plane is a countable set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

From Kolmogorov's Introductory Real Analysis. I am doing some self-study and would like some feedback on whether my proof is correct.

I am using that the set of rational numbers is countable as given, and I am invoking the following Theorem which is proved in the book.

**Theorem 2**. The union of a finite or countable number of countable sets $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ is itself countable.

**Claim**. The set of all rational points in the plane (points with rational coordinates) is countable.

*Proof*.
Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable set, we can write $\mathbb{Q} = \{q_1, q_2, q_3, \ldots\}$. If we fix $q_1$ we can define the following set:
$$
Q_1 = \{(q_1, q)\;|\; q\in\mathbb{Q}\},
$$
which are all the rational points in the plane with $q_1$ in the $x$ position. We can create a one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb{Q}$ by simply setting $p\leftrightarrow (q_1, p)$ for each $p\in\mathbb{Q}$, which shows
that $Q_1$ is countable. We can now define the following union which includes all rational points in the plane:
$$
\mathcal{Q} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty Q_n,
$$
which is a countable union of countable sets. By Theorem 2, $\mathcal{Q}$ is a countable set.
■

Comment: This seems fine except that you defined $Q_1$ but didn't actually define $Q_i$ for any other $i$.  This should be explicitly stated that $Q_i = \{(q_i,q)\mid q\in \Bbb Q\}$

Comment: All right, great! Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: As a stylistic choice, it may help as well to not overuse the letter $q$ here.  You have five different types of $q$ appearing $(\Bbb Q, \mathcal{Q}, Q_i, q_i, q)$ which may make it difficult for some readers to follow along if they weren't well familiar with what you are doing.  For such a short proof as this it might not matter, but in a longer more involved proof this could cause several headaches.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I just kept adding them as I was typing it out, but it does get a bit much. Thanks again!

Comment: @CoveredInChocolate Reopened. Good to go!

Comment: You don't need to talk of writing out $\mathbb Q$ as $\{q_1, q_2, .... \}$.  You could simply note that: $\mathbb Q$ is countable.  And the for each $q\in\mathbb Q$ define set $Q_q = \{(q,p): p\in \mathbb Q\}$.  Show $\mathbb Q\leftrightarrow Q_q$ via $p\leftrightarrow (p,q)$ is a bijection.  Then $\mathscr Q = \bigcup_{q\in \mathbb Q} Q_q$ is a countable union.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Many thanks! :)

Comment: @JMoravitz . The awesome mathematician Stavo Todocevic had a tendency to do that. I recall an oral presentation where he had several different x's on the blackboard at once.

Comment: @fleablood: Noted. I was mostly concerned that my proof wasn't correct. But since it is, I can start focusing more on form and presentation. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Your proof is correct.  Key point is noting $p \leftrightarrow (p,q)$ is bijection between $\{(p,q)|p\in \mathbb Q\}\leftrightarrow \mathbb Q$ (depending on how picky your professor wants you to demonstrate knowledge of the definitions you may be asked to prove that but that just be a matter of stating the definitions) And that therefore $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q = \bigcup_{q\in Q}\{(p,q)|p\in \mathbb Q\}$ is a countable union of countable sets.... It's a good proof.

Comment: Independently of whether or not the question is on topic or off-topic, please avoid adding meta comments in the body of your question, and avoid at all costs from adding them on the top. That's the part that is visible when people search or use Google.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Sorry. I removed them now.

Comment: @CoveredInChocolate Good job. You can @ people who have replied to you and politely request an answer or further conversation. Thank you for your consideration of site matters.

Answer (score 0):

From the feedback in the comments the proof has been verified to be correct (with some suggestions for writing it a bit clearer).

Will mark this as solved. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Isn't it more useful to take your answer from the question and put it in an answer instead?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: You mean my proof? Certainly, if you think that is better.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly better. Even better, take your answer and post it on the suggested duplicate and delete this one. The site earns a well-written answer and loses a question that is effectively a duplicate ("how to prove X") or essentially useless for any future interactions ("Is this specific proof that I wrote good? Yes, it is.").